# Is $(\frac{2y+5}{y-3}=x)$ the same as $(\frac{-2y-5}{3-y}=x)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am doing an exam paper and I get an answer similar to what the markscheme suggests. It said ($\frac{2y+5}{y-3}=x$)- let's call this $A$- was the answer on the mark scheme and I was wondering if it is the same as my answer $:(\frac{-2y-5}{3-y}=x)$- let's call it $B$.
I understand how to get to both from the original equation of $(x-2=\frac{3x+5}{y})$ and have tried plugging numbers. As far as I can see it works, but I am unsure whether there is a difference, for example if I use $-2$ as $y$, I get $x$ as $\frac{-1}{5}$ for $A$ and $\frac{1}{-5}$ for $B$.

Comment: Use LaTeX, otherwise we don't see that you want to say.

Comment: For more info on latex, check out [this quickreference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on typesetting math on Math.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, these are the same.
$$\frac{2y+5}{y-3}=\frac{-1}{-1}\bigg(\frac{2y+5}{y-3}\bigg)=\frac{-2y-5}{-y+3}=\frac{-2y-5}{3-y}$$

Comment: Thank you ever so much